# How do I change Intellij IDEA's default project path?

Tags: intellij-idea

I would like to change IntelliJ IDEA's default project path. Right now it's set to ~/IdeaProjects.  However, guides only tell me how to change the project directory on a per-project basis, and new projects will still go to ~/IdeaProjects by default. How can I change the default directory to something like ~/other-dir/IdeaProjects?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The default path will be changed once you change it in the "New project" dialog:

[image]

Information about the changed location is stored in [IDE configuration directory](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/directories-used-by-the-ide-to-store-settings-caches-plugins-and-logs.html#config-directory), `options/recentProjects.xml` file:

[image]